# Is it possible to use same hostname with multiple Ingress resources running in different namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to use the same hostname let's say `example.com` with multiple Ingress resources running in different namespaces i.e `monitoring` and `myapp`. I'm using **Kubernetes nginx-ingress** controller.

**haproxy-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: haproxy-ingress
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"  
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    # fill in host here
    - example.com
    
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: haproxy
                port:
                  number: 80
```

**grafana-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          # only match /grafana and paths under /grafana/
          - path: /grafana(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: grafana
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

When I'm doing `curl example.com` then it is redirecting me to the deployment running in namespace one(as expected) but when I'm doing `curl example.com/grafana` then still it is redirecting me to namespace one deployment.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

There can be two issues in your case.

One is you don't need the regex path for grafana ingress. Simple `/grafana` path will be fine with path type `Prefix` as with path type `Prefix` any `/grafana/...` will be redirected associated service. So the manifest file will be:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /grafana
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: grafana
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

And the second issue can be the related service or deployment might not be the under same namespace `monitoring`. Please make sure the deployment/service/secret or other resources needed for grafana remains under the same namespace `monitoring`.

Comment: Thanks, Pulak for responding. I'll try it by removing regex part. Yes services and other related things are running in the `monitoring` namespace only.

Comment: after adding `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` it started working. But your suggestion helped a lot. Thank you so much for the help.